# A possible generalization of "homotopy" to study group actions of various kinds

Tags: gr.group-theory, homotopy-theory, algebraic-groups

This is a naive question about abstract homotopy theory by someone who knows nothing about it, except that it involves some generalization of the notion of "homotopy".

If we think of $O(n)$ as acting via isometries on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $SO(n)$ is the group of orientation-preserving isometries. One natural way to define an orientation-preserving isometry is that it is homotopic to the identity map, in the following sense:

Let a **path between isometries** be defined as a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow O(n)$, and we abbreviate $f_t=f(t)$.

The path $f$ is said to be continuous if for every $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the trajectory $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $g(t)=f_t(p)$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So an isometry $\tau$ is **orientation-preserving** if there is a continuous path $f:[0,1]\rightarrow O(n)$ such that $f_0=\text{identity}$ and $f_1=\tau$.

Put differently, $\tau$ is orientation-preserving if there is a homotopy between the identity and $\tau$.

---

**A more general situation:** We have a group $G$ and an object $X$, and $G$ acts on $X$ via structure-preserving transformations.

Is there an **interesting** way to generalize the notion of "homotopy", such that we can say two elements $g,h\in G$ are "homotopic"? This notion of "homotopy" would depend both on $G$ and $X$.

If such a generalization were possible, the homotopy equivalence class of the identity would be a subgroup. In the case $G=O(n)$ acting on $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, this subgroup would be $SO(n)$.

I also expect:

- In the case $G=GL(n,F)$ acting on the vector space $F^n$, the homotopy equivalence class of the identity would be $SL(n,F)$
- In the case $G=S_n$ acting on the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$, the homotopy equivalence class of the identity would be $A_n$.

Comment: The generalization that is most commonly used is to climb up the Whitehead tower of the orthogonal group.  After orientation-preserving, you get spin-structure preserving.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is take the standard real representation of $S_n$, which is a homomorphism $S_n\to O(n)$. Then $A_n$ is the pre-image of the path component of the identity in $O(n)$, i.e., $SO(n)$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the post in a misleading way. I've edited the post (the title and body) to make my question clearer.